# Having trouble using NSDateFormatter (stringFromDate) in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

Having trouble using NSDateFormatter in Swift, can someone help?
Below code prints nothing.

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
```

Comment: Read [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html) reference

Answer (score 19):

Make you set either the dateFormat (or dateStyle).

Here's a complete example that breaks it down to make it easier to see what you're missing.

The specific line you want to pay attention to is one where you need to set the dateFormat of the dateFormatter. Here we're setting it to "yyyy-MM-dd" which will give an output like "2014-06-22".

```
func formatADate() {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let d = NSDate()
    let s = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(d)
    println(s)
}
```

Then you can call formatADate().

Check out the [NSDateFormatter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdateformatter_class/Reference/Reference.html) for further info.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I just wanted to share a quick 'Gotcha': the timeStyle property counts as a dateStyle. I had an NSFormatter() and set timeStyle = .NoStyle and then went to set the dateFormat, and was puzzled at first as to why I was getting an empty string. After looking at your example it dawned on me that setting the dateFormat WAS accounting for what the time would also do/look like and that setting the timeStyle to none wasn't necessary, and in fact causing my problem.  Don't set both the timeFormat and a dateStyle

Comment: Note: dateFormatter can be a constant, i.e let rather than var.

Answer (score 6):

Did you make sure to set the date style? If you don't, it will output an empty string.

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle
println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `UIDatePicker`:

```
@IBAction func whenDateChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

    let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)

    self.dateLabel.text = strDate

}
```